# Double being displayed with unnecessary zeros after decimal

Tags: objective-c++

In my calculator app, I am trying to display a "double" value in a UILabel. However, the value always has more zeros than it needs. For example, 64 is displayed as 64.000000, 4.23 is displayed as 4.230000, etc.

How can I make it display only as many decimal places as fits?

```
vector<Token> postfix;  // create empty postfix vector
infixToPostfix(infix, postfix);  // call inToPost to fill up postfix vector from infix vector
answer = postFixEvaluate(postfix); // evaluate expression

expString.clear();
expNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", answer]; // convert "answer" to NSString
displayScreen.text = expNSString; // display answer in UIlabel "displayScreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [`[NSString stringWithFormat:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) class reference:

**Parameters**

> format A format string. See “[Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)” for
>   examples of how to use this method, and “[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)” for
>   a list of format specifiers. This value must not be nil.

and following the first link, one of the first examples is:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A string: %@, a float: %1.2f",
                                               @"string", 31415.9265]; //  ^
// string1 is "A string: string, a float: 31415.93"
```

You need to learn to think for yourself.  Read the documentation!

Comment: The problem is, I don't want there to always be only 2 decimal places as %1.2f would cause. I want it to vary depending on how many "real" decimal places there are.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but did you try `%g`? This will produce scientific notation in some cases:

> 64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise.

But, as it says, you can control this to some extent using the precision field: if your numbers are large, you will need to increase the precision to avoid scientific notation. If your numbers are small, then I think there is nothing you can do about it when using `%g`.

I get this output:

```
    64.0 -> "64"
    64.1 -> "64.1"
    64.15555 -> "64.1556" // default precision is 6
```